# How do I use Video tag in HTMl in this cod

Tags: html

I have this code but it doesn't load video.

```
<video width="500" height="400" controls>
 <source src="C:\Users\Shruti\Desktop\index.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />
 </video>
```

Comment: Type `C:\Users\Shruti\Desktop\index.mp4` url in your chrome address bar and check if video exist or not. Or check in console for 404 error

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to check if the file path is correct and is accessible.

```
<video width="500" height="400" controls="">
  <source src="C:/Users/Shruti/Desktop/index.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```

Try to navigate to the path in explorer by just submitting the URL.

```
C:/Users/Shruti/Desktop/index.mp4
```

Also when uploading or may previewing you will have to provide absolute or relative paths to make the URL work.

```
<video width="500" height="400" controls="">
  <source src="/SomeFolderInWebspace/index.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```